# Python Cv2 Tesseract Improve readability on thick numbers?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

My images are about 50% correct on what numbers are on the screen.

Numbers look like this.

[image: test3]

My code givs me this result [164609, 7097394, 2259]

How can I improve my code so it would read this more accurate?  I have tried changing the white tones up and down with mixed results. And i've tried changing my PSM and OEM settings.

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
    region = {
        'left': 3577,
        'top': 146,
        'width': 171,
        'height': 130
    }

    image = sct.grab(region)
    mss.tools.to_png(image.rgb, image.size, output='loot1.png')

rawImage = cv2.imread('test3.png') 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rawImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_white = np.array([0,0,230])
higher_white = np.array([255,255,255])
white_range = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, higher_white)



data = pytesseract.image_to_string(white_range, lang='eng',config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

numbers = [
    int(m)
    for line in data.splitlines()
    if (m := "".join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit())).isnumeric()
]  
cv2.imshow("White", white_range)
cv2.waitKey()

    
print(numbers)
```

Edit:
manged to get the image white with black text. I enhanced the image and also manged to blur it.

[image]

My code so far.

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
    region = {
        'left': 3577,
        'top': 146,
        'width': 171,
        'height': 130
    }

    image = sct.grab(region)
    mss.tools.to_png(image.rgb, image.size, output='loot1.png')

    rawImage = cv2.imread('test4.png')

    
    # Make Image bigger
    scale_percent = 260 # percent of original size
    width = int(rawImage.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(rawImage.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized = cv2.resize(rawImage, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    #Thin the numbers
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
    rawImage = cv2.erode(resized, kernel)
    
    #Find the white and remove everything else
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_white = np.array([0,0,235])
    higher_white = np.array([255,255,255])
    white_range = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, higher_white)
    white_range = cv2.bitwise_not(white_range)

    #Blur image
    ksize = (9,9)
    white_range = cv2.blur(white_range,ksize)

    #Sharpen image
    # sharp = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
    #                   [-1,9,-1],
    #                   [-1,-1,-1]])
    # sharp2 = cv2.filter2D(white_range, -1, sharp)

    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(white_range, lang='eng',config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

numbers = [
    int(m)
    for line in data.splitlines()
    if (m := "".join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit())).isnumeric()
]  
cv2.imshow("White", white_range)
cv2.waitKey()

    
print(numbers)
```

However sharpening is not working out. If I use this code to try and sharpen it, it gets abit cracked.

```
sharp = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
[-1,9,-1],
[-1,-1,-1]])
sharp2 = cv2.filter2D(white_range, -1, sharp)
```

Like this

[image: Cracked after sharp]

playing around with the array for sharpening often makes the picture complete black. Like changing the 9 to a 4 = black screen.
Any help on how I would go from here?

Comment: first you could convert to black text on white background, you can alse rescale image. It may have problem when text is too small (or too big). See more in Tesseract documentation [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)

Comment: Ok, i've tried rescaling and also tried to erode.  I can't find a good way to convert the black into white and white into black.  Any way you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: first you could describein question what you already tried - we can't read in you rmind and we may waste time to show direction which you already tried. I was thinking about resizing, next bluring and eventually sharpening to make more rounded borders. Next idea is to train tesseract on your numbers but I never did it and it may need a lot of work.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to be more clear.
I found a way to convert just now, using 'cv2.bitwise_not(rawImage)'
I will play around abit more and see what kind of results I get. 
Training tesseract sounds interesting though. I might look into that aswell

Comment: because image is `numpy.array` (which can make operation on all values without using `for`-loop) with values `0..255` so to invert image I used `img = 255 - img`

Comment: edited my post with some new information.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert image:

[image]

and when I run tesseract:

```
tesseract inverted.png -
```

I got this results:

```
164 609
709794
2 259
```